# Accessing https://data.stackexchange.com/query APIs programmatically

Tags: support, data-explorer, api

All, We want to get the list of all deleted question Id's from StackOverflow (with additional tags and/or date filters, if possible). However we don't see an useful API for this here:
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

So instead we attempted using StackExchange Data Explorer to compose a query like this and it seems to work fine - either with a logged in user or anonymously with captcha validated.

select
Id
from PostsWithDeleted
where posttypeid = 1 and DeletionDate is not Null

How do we use this https://data.stackexchange.com/query API programmatically (with an API key/ access token)? Is this supported? If not, are there any other alternatives to get the list of deleted question Ids?

Thanks.

Comment: The API doesn't expose information about deleted posts. There is no official API for SEDE, but it's possible to simulate browsing the site; see my answer in the linked question. Also, to access any useful information about deleted posts, you need an account with 10k reputation on Stack Overflow ...

Comment: Answering the question as-written: how about retrieving all non-deleted Id's and seeing which are missing? They go more or less in order. If you have 1, 4 and 10, you know 2-3, 5-9 are missing. This should give you a list of all deleted question Id's. Won't do you much good though...